# How to set proxy user in Livy Job submit through its Java API

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, livy

I am using Livy's Java API to submit a spark job on YARN on my cluster. Currently the jobs are being submitted as 'livy' user, but I want to submit the job as a proxy user from Livy.

It is possible to do this by sending POST request to the Livy server, by passing a field in the POST data. I was thinking if this could be done by Livy's Java API.

I am using the standard way to submit a Job:

```
LivyClient client = new LivyClientBuilder()
  .setURI(new URI(livyUrl))
  .build();

try {
  System.err.printf("Uploading %s to the Spark context...\n", piJar);
  client.uploadJar(new File(piJar)).get();

  System.err.printf("Running PiJob with %d samples...\n", samples);
  double pi = client.submit(new PiJob(samples)).get();

  System.out.println("Pi is roughly: " + pi);
} finally {
  client.stop(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting answer to my own question.
Currently there is no way to set the proxy user through the LivyClientBuilder.

A workaround for this is:

1. Create the session through the REST API (POST request to `< livy-server >/session/` ) and read the session ID from the request's response. Proxy user can be set via the REST API by passing it in the POST data: `{"kind": "spark", "proxyUser": "lok"}`
2. Once the session is created, connect to it using the ID via LivyClientBuilder ( livyURL would be `< livy-server >/sessions/< id >/` ).